# Trust anchor for certification path not found exception

Tags: android, tomcat, exception, ssl, https

Hi I'm trying to establish ssl communication between tomcat server and android app using https

1- I used keytool to create a keystore file for tomcat

2- then generate a pem file to use it with keytool to generate a BKS file

3- the tomcat server is working fine

basically I followed this article

The problem is when I try to Connect from android app using HttpsURLConnection I always get the exception :

---

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:351)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:1323)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1225)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:395)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:298)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:399)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:110)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:221)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
at org.apache.cordova.rest.Rest.send(Rest.java:177)
```

---

help !!

Comment: sorry this the article I followed : http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/login-application-for-android-android.html#.VseOImjJzI

Comment: The 3 most common reasons are listed for this error are listed at https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems . If this is a server that is accessible via the Internet, use a tool like SSL Labs Server test https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html to determine if it is one of these reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solution

1) If you are using Self Signed Certificate try adding the certificate (.crt / .cer) to the truststore.

2) If your certificate is signed by your local CA make sure you import the root CA and intermediate CA to the trust store.

Answer (score 0):

```
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream caInput = getApplicationContext().getResources()
                    .openRawResource(R.raw.my_certificate);//new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Certificate ca;
            try {
                ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            } finally {
                caInput.close();
            }

            /** Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs **/
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

            /**Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore **/
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            /** Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager **/
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

and finally set the sslcontext to your [HttpsURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)